# EJB Asynchronous method Interceptors : is it possible to execute interceptor method in the caller thread

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb, interceptor, ejb-3.1

If a method annotated with @Asynchronous, has an interceptor, the @AroundInvoke method gets executed in the same thread that will execute the asynchronous method, is it possible to make the execution of the interceptor method happens in the thread that made the call to the async method?

This is to propagate data from caller thread to the thread that will execute the async method

bellow a code snippet I used to test this :

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceA{
  @Asynchronous
  @Interceptors(ServiceAInterceptor.class)
  public void m1(){ ... }
}

public class ServiceAInterceptor{
  @AroundInvoke
  public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    ...
    return context.proceed();
  }
}

@Stateless
public class ServiceB{
  public void m2(){
    serviceA.m1();
  }
}
```

Even if @Interceptors is moved to the class level, the behavior will be the same.

**Thanks for any help**

Comment: Quite sure that you can not achieve that. Why don't you just pass the data as argument of the async method?

Comment: because I can't change an existing code, Is there any specification that state this ?I think using @Asyn above a method suggests that only its code will be executed in an  async context, isn't it ?

Comment: No, not only it's code. But the whole EJB proxy wrapper as well, which manages transactions, runs interceptors, etc.

Comment: is there any specification that states what u said in the first comment must be the behavior of the interceptors?

Comment: No, ejb spec does not mention that, and it's too obvious to talk about I think. And it does not ever propose any threading option for interceptors for the same reason.